# are differents jvm compatibles between themselves?

Tags: jvm, weblogic, compatibility, java, jrockit

I have a question about weblogic:
I have a weblogic instance that runs on jdk, and I have applications deployed on this server (.war files). 
If I change the startup parameters and I tell it that runs on jrockit, are the applications (.war files) deployed in it compatibles?, or must I mantain the original jdk?.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The SUN JDK and BEA Jrockit are both compatible to each other when it comes to running standard Java code. To give an example, weblogic server itself is Java code which can run on sun JDK and Jrockit. similarly your .war application will work just fine in both the JVM's

What different between these JVM's is the way they do garbage collection for example, or code compression options and so on. Though the difference is getting blurred each passing day as both are owned by Oracle now.